# Pygame not using specified font

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

So I am having a problem in pygame where I specify the font and size to use, but when my program is run, the font and size are the default.

Here is where I define the text

```
def font(self):
    '''*****FATAL - THIS LINE CAUSES ERROR (When compiled to .exe using cx_freeze)*****'''
    #font = pygame.font.SysFont("Coure", 20)
    font_color = (0, 0, 0)
    font = pygame.font.Font("coure.fon", 20)
    self.text = font.render("Level "+str(self.level) + " " + self.name + " Health " + str(self.health), True, font_color)
```

The line commented out under the "Fatal" comment works perfectly when run from the editor, however causes this error once it is run as an .exe

```
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pygame\pkgdata.py", line 67, in   getResource
return open(os.path.normpath(path), 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:    'C:\\Users\\Jared\\Desktop\\Python\\Boss Battle\\build\\exe.win32-3.4\\library.zip\\pygame\\freesansbold.ttf'
```

I don't have the freesansbold font installed on my computer, but that shouldn't matter, since it should be looking for the coure font in the folder of the game. The weird thing is that I say "Coure" and the file is named "coure.fon", but when I write that, it is unrecognized.

I guess Im looking for some guidence on how to fix either the error, or how to define which text file I want it to use. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is the only error about the missing font if so it's an easy fix that I can walk you through, as I had the same problem and found the fix 3 days later.

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax if you have solution then add it as answer :)

Comment: @furas Fine, even though the people that ask questions about changing python to an exe don't normally ever come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up your pygame package folder. It should be something like `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pygame`. There should be a True Type Font File titled `freesansbold.ttf`. Copy that file then open the folder containing your exe program. There should be a zipped file called library. Open it up and go to the pygame folder inside the zipped file. Should look something like this `\build\exe.win32-3.4\library.zip\pygame`. And just paste the `freesansbold.ttf` file in that folder and it should work perfectly. The freesansbold font comes with the pygame package, but for some reason `py2exe` and `cx_Freeze` don't include it, so you have to add it manually.

Comment: Thank you! If there is anything else just ask.