# Fatal Error when converting game in pygame to exe

Tags: python, pygame, cx-freeze

This is the code I am using to create the build file:

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("SpeedRacer.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="SpeedRacer",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages": ["pygame"],"include_files": ["SpeedRacerDefaultCar.png"]}},

    executables = executables

    )
```

This is the error I get when launching .exe file for game:

```
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: cHRM chunk does not match sRGB
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pygame\pkgdata.py". line 67. in getResourc
e
        return open(os.path.normpath(path), 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Jordan\\Desk
top\\Python Projects\\Game Ideas\\SpeedRacerGame\\build\\exe.win-amd64-3.4\\libr
ary.zip\\pygame\\freesansbold.ttf'
```

Game Code is as follows:

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

display_width = 1440
display_height = 900

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

red = (200,0,0)
green = (50,126,31)
blue = (34,101,183)

bright_green = (72,185,45)
bright_red = (255,0,0)

block_color = green

car_width = 75 # Image width in Pixels.

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((1440, 900))
pygame.display.set_caption('SpeedRacer')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load('SpeedRacerDefaultCar.png')

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def things_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Dodged: "+str(count), True, bright_red)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (0, 0))

def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])


def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y))

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, blue)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.SysFont(None,115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)

    game_loop()

def crash():
    message_display('You Crashed')

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    print(click)
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, (x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont(None,20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText,)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(black)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont(None,115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("SpeedRacer", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("Start",550,575,100,50,green,bright_green,game_loop)
        button("Quit",750,575,100,50,red,bright_red,quitgame)


        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def game_loop():

    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)

    x_change = 0

    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 4
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100

    Dodged = 0

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -10

                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 10

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0


        x += x_change
        gameDisplay.fill(black)

        # things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color)
        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, block_color)
        thing_starty += thing_speed
        car(x,y)
        things_dodged(Dodged)

        if x > display_width - car_width or x < 0:
            crash()


        if thing_starty > display_height:
            thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
            thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
            Dodged += 1
            thing_speed += 0.4
            thing_width += (Dodged * 0.4)




        if y < thing_starty+thing_height:
            print('y crossover')

            if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x+car_width > thing_startx and x + car_width < thing_startx+thing_width:
                print('x crossover')
                crash()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(120)


game_intro()
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

I converted to .exe using cx_Freeze.

Comment: ...pygame\\freesansbold.ttf - Does this path/file exist?

Comment: Please don't tag your text editor. It has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Lpk.. It doesnt. But i have tried changing all the font in the program to default SysFont and it still doesnt solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Hi please try to see the following web pages, which explains how to resolve the problem, actually I had the same problem and I made the things that they suggested and now is working:

First I made:

Original line code

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
```

Change line code by this

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 48)
```

[Using pygame2exe and having font issue with sysfont/.ttf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113413/using-pygame2exe-and-having-font-issue-with-sysfont-ttf)

[Pygame not using specified font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34841268/pygame-not-using-specified-font)